# Python How to share a serial port with two different threads (Class A, Class B)

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

I have a single Python process which is using a serial port (unique resource) which is managed using an instance of a class A. There exists two different threads initialized using instances of classes B and C, which are constantly using the serial port resource through the objected already created.

```
import threading

Class A(threading.Thread):
    #Zigbee serial port handler
    def __init__(self,dev):
        #something here that initialize serial port
    def run():
        while True:
            #listening serial interface
    def pack(self):
        #something
    def checksum(self):
        #something
    def write(self):
        #something

Class B(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,SerialPortHandler):
        self.serialporthandler=SerialPortHandler
    def run(self)
        while True:
            #something that uses self.serialporthandler

Class C(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,SerialPortHandler):
        self.serialporthandler=SerialPortHandler
    def run(self)
        while True:
            #something that uses self.serialporthandler

def main():
    a=A('/dev/ttyUSB1')
    b=B(a)
    b.start()
    c=C(a)
    c.start()

if __name__=='main':
    while True:
        main()
```

The problem is that both threads are trying to access the serial resource at the same time. I could use several instances of the same class A, attaching Lock.acquire() and Lock.release() in the sensitive parts.

Could some of you point me to the right way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While you *could* share the serial port using appropriate locking, I wouldn't recommend it. I've written several multi-threaded applications that communicate on the serial port in Python, and in my experience the following approach is better:

- Have a single class, in a single thread, manage the actual serial port communication, via a `Queue` object or two:

  - Stuff read from the port is placed into the queue
  - Commands to send to the port are placed into the queue and the "Serial thread" sends them
- Have the other threads implement logic by placing things into the queue and taking things out

Using `Queue` objects will greatly simplify your code and make it more robust.

This approach opens a lot of possibilities for you in terms of design. You can, for example, register events (callbacks) with the serial thread manager and have it call them (in a synchronized way) when interesting events occur, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `threading.Lock()` to `class A` and make it acquire the lock when using it:

```
def __init__(self,dev):
    self.lock = threading.Lock()

def read(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    data = ? #whatever you need to do here to read
    self.lock.release()
    return data

def write(self, data):
    self.lock.acquire()
    #whatever you need to do to write
    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: Locks are good, it's just that in Python you use them like `with self.lock: return something()`

Comment: Assuming OP is using 2.6 or later.

Comment: Beware of exceptions being thrown while you're holding the lock. Using `with` (Python 2.6+) here or `try/finally` would be prudent.

Comment: @singularity I didn't mean to cause any offense to you, but I felt that your answer still wasn't thread safe, which can be a very tricky thing to get right. If you feel my answer is incorrect, then by all means, __please__ -1 and propose a correction. Thanks :)