# How to share a resouce (a serial port) with several threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I currently have a program with 4 threads.

4 Threads are "Worker Threads" that each have a dedicated serial port that monitors a dedicated device.  So Worker Thread 1 monitors Com port 1, Thread 2 monitors Com Port 2 etc.

All this all working fine. No conflicts.

However, the 4 worker threads all have to send commands to a 5th  Comm Port as well, which is a communication link to a device that can powercycle the other devices.
I.E. they all have to share a specific resource, the 5th com port.

When they do send a command to this 5th shared each thread has to wait until the command has finished before continuing.

I've followed the coding example from Dan (thanks!) and tried to form a prototype test code.
This SEEMS to work.

I would appreciate a critical review of the code to see if I'm going in the right direction.

Apologies if I'm not explaining this very well as whilst I've used threads before. Handling a shared resource is new to me.  Also I'm just getting to grips with how Stackoverflow works!!

Many thanks

Comment: for the collisions, why don't you have one class and access the serial port from there (that way, it only gets opened once,). Also, how about adding a buffer and writing your data to the next available space in the 'queue'?

Comment: something similar is actually suggested here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/4043762/3436942

Comment: Do you mean each thread calling this class? Wouldnt this be thread-unsafe because the class is still calling a shared resouce.  For example, one thread may call the class to write to the serial port whilst another may be already reading from it.  Or do you mean for the class to open the port and accept messages from other threads putting them into a queue of actions?  If so how would I share the class between the threads?

Comment: That was what I was suggesting (second part), yes. but as you have just pointed out, it could also cause (rare, but possible) collisions in the queue. Why don't you include something like a 'lock' - telling the other threads the serial is in use. In terms of 'best way', it would be better for a **single** thread writing the data, and a **single ** thread reading it. It was to my previous mistakes (i had a serial port being read in two different threads) where every other byte was read in one and the other half was read in the other thread.

Comment: Write a single class with a single `Shared` instance of the serial port object. `SyncLock` calls to that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified solution using a shared instance of a resource and a lock.

```
Public Class Resource
    Public Function Read() As String
        Return "result"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ResourceUser
    Private Shared resourceLock As New Object
    Private Shared r As New Resource()
    Public Function Read()
        Dim res As String
        SyncLock resourceLock
            res = r.Read()
        End SyncLock
        Return res
    End Function
End Class
```

Example usage:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoSomethingWithResourceUser)
    Dim t2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoSomethingWithResourceUser)
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingWithResourceUser()
    Dim ru As New ResourceUser()
    ru.Read()
End Sub
```

Comment: So, if I follow this correctly, I could have each thread instantiate a ResourceUser Object on startup (as the threads need regular communication with the Serial Port), then when a thread wants to use the Serial Port, it just calls ResourceUser.WhatEverFUnctionIsNeeded? And the ResourceUser Object, then controls a related call to a WhatEverFUnctionIsNeeded on the Object that handles the serial port?

Comment: The reason for the thread using another Class to handle the Serial port class is so the "ResouceUser" class can handle the locking?

Comment: @user3844416 Yes, everything you're saying is accurate. Let the class closest to the resource manage it.

Comment: @user3844416 See me other answer more specific to comms and allowing multiple comm ports.

Comment: Ive tried a test project running this pattern of coding.  Seems to work almost apart from thread 4 not getting a look in after an initial start.  I'll try and enter the code here.  If it would be more appropriate I'll put in as a new question...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But the way the lock works is if some thread has locked it, other threads can't so they will be stuck on that line indefinitely until no other thread has locked it. It's possible one of the other threads has errored out and not released the lock. You should put a try-catch inside the lock to ensure you handle exceptions and can release the lock when done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example more specific to serial comms. It uses a dictionary to keep track of physical comm resources and their relevant locks, so that you can do asynchronous access to different comm ports, but synchronize access to each single comm port.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim c1 As New CommPortThreadSafe("COM1")
    Dim c2 As New CommPortThreadSafe("COM2")
    Dim c3 As New CommPortThreadSafe("COM1")
    Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(Sub() c1.Read())
    Dim t2 As New Threading.Thread(Sub() c2.Read())
    Dim t3 As New Threading.Thread(Sub() c3.Read())
    ' t1 and t3 can't be in critical region at same time
    ' t2 will be able to run through critical region
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
    t3.Start()
End Sub

Public Class CommPort
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Function Read() As String
        Return "result"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CommPortThreadSafe
    Private Shared resourceLocks As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
    Private Shared comms As New Dictionary(Of String, CommPort)()
    Private Shared collectionLock As New Object()
    Private commPortName As String
    ' constructor takes the comm port name
    ' so the appropriate dictionaries can be set up
    Public Sub New(commPortName As String)
        SyncLock collectionLock
            Me.commPortName = commPortName
            If Not comms.ContainsKey(commPortName) Then
                Dim c As New CommPort()
                Dim o As New Object()
                c.Name = commPortName
                ' configure comm port further etc.
                comms.Add(commPortName, c)
                resourceLocks.Add(commPortName, o)
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
    Public Function Read()
        Dim res As String
        SyncLock resourceLocks(Me.commPortName)
            res = comms(Me.commPortName).Read()
        End SyncLock
        Return res
    End Function
End Class
```

**To address your recent edits:**

Threads A would all declare the comm port in the same way. Actually this is a benefit of this pattern (similar to multiton pattern) which works like a singleton when only one comm port is used. This code could be used in all threads:

```
Dim myCommPort As New CommPortThreadSafe("COM1")
```

The lock inside the read is going to synchronize access to COM1 because "COM1" (the name of the comm port) is actually the key to the `Dictionary<string, object>` used for locking. So when any thread reaches this code, keying with the same key, that region will be accessible only to a single thread because they all use the same key.

```
SyncLock resourceLocks(Me.commPortName)
    res = comms(Me.commPortName).Read()
End SyncLock
```

As you saw, that string is set up in the constructor so as long as all the threads create their object passing the same string to the constructor, they will all have underlying indirect references to the same `CommPort`. The constructor can only create the instance if the name doesn't already exist in its dictionary:

```
 If Not comms.ContainsKey(commPortName) Then
     Dim c As New CommPort()
```

Here's another example usage with just one comm port:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ts As New ThreadStart(
        Sub()
            Dim c As New CommPortThreadSafe("COM1")
            For i As Integer = 0 To 99
                c.Read()
            Next
        End Sub)
    Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(ts)
    Dim t2 As New Threading.Thread(ts)
    Dim t3 As New Threading.Thread(ts)
    Dim t4 As New Threading.Thread(ts)
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
    t3.Start()
    t4.Start()
End Sub
```

In this example we start 4 threads which each perform the code in the threadstart. There is a loop reading the comm port. If you test this out, you will see that it is thread-safe as long as the entire read takes place inside `Read()`, which you will need to develop of course. You may have another layer in which you are sending custom commands and waiting for a response. These two actions should both be inside a single SyncLock in each custom function. Thread B should use the same class if it's doing a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I need to spend some time on reiewing this.  Cheers

Comment: Hi Dan. Again thanks for this.  However, it's confusing me a bit, as I only have a single Comm port to worry about.  I've edited the question to hopefully explain a little more.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry didnt mean to! I might have pressed an edit button but didnt deliberately mean to change anything.  Thanks for your help Dan.  I think the resourceUser method seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

FORM CODE FOR TESTING

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Worker(4) As jWorker                    '4 Worker Object
    Public myWorkerThread(4) As Threading.Thread    '4 runtime threads

    Private Checker As jChecker                 '1 Checking Object
    Public myCheckerThread As Threading.Thread  ' Thread to check status of Resource

    Dim MainThreadResouce As jResourceUser

    'Assume the actual serial port is opened here
    'so its available for access by the jResource Object.

    'Pressing button 1 will start up all the threads
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'setup a another ResourceUser object here so can see one of the shared values from the form.
        MainThreadResouce = New jResourceUser

        'Setup and start worker threads - basically these do work and regularly 
        'send commands to a shared resource
        For I = 1 To 4
            Worker(I) = New jWorker
            Worker(I).id = I
            myWorkerThread(I) = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Worker(I).doWork)
            myWorkerThread(I).Start()
        Next I

        'Start Checking thread - regularly checks something in the resource
        'please ignore this for now!
        Checker = New jChecker
        myCheckerThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Checker.dochecking)
        myCheckerThread.Start()

    End Sub
End Class
```

========================
WORKER THREAD, MODELLING THE MONITORING THREADS

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class jWorker

    Private _id As Integer = 0
    Private _workCount As Integer = 0
    Private resourceUser As jResourceUser

    Public workerStatus As String = ""

    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            Me._id = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property count() As Integer
        Get
            Return _workCount
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        resourceUser = New jResourceUser
    End Sub

    Sub doWork()
        workerStatus = "Started"
        Do Until False
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            _workCount += 1

            If _workCount Mod 5 = 0 Then

                'THe line below would cause a bottleneck
                'As it prevents the system trying to powercycle any other
                'modems whilst its doing just one.
                'resourceUser.PowerCycle(_id)

                Debug.Print("W" & _id & ", Worker - Requesting Power OFF +++++++++++++")
                resourceUser.Poweroff(_id)
                Debug.Print("W" & _id & ", Worker - Waiting 10 secs for modem to settle")
                Thread.Sleep(10000)
                Debug.Print("W" & _id & ", Worker - Requesting Power ON")
                resourceUser.PowerOn(_id)
                Debug.Print("W" & _id & ", Worker - Finished Power cycle ------------")
            End If

        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

===================
RESOURCE USER - TO CONTROL ACCESS TO SHARED RESOURCE

```
Public Class jResourceUser
    'Variables for handling resouce locking
    Private Shared resourceLock As New Object
    Private Shared _resource As New jResource("Com1", "ON")
    'keeps a status of which workers have signalled an OFF or ON via the Resource
    'in the form of a string 11213141  (device number (1-4) - 1 for on, 0 for off

    Private Shared _powerStatus As String

    Public ReadOnly Property PowerStatus As String
        Get
            Return _powerStatus
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        _powerStatus = _resource.PowerState
    End Sub

    Sub PowerOn(ByVal WorkerID As Integer)
        Debug.Print("W" & WorkerID & ",  ResouceUser -  requesting Lock for Power ON [" & _powerStatus & "]")
        SyncLock resourceLock
            _resource.TurnOn(WorkerID)
            _powerStatus = _resource.PowerState
            Debug.Print("W" & WorkerID & ",  ResouceUser - Turned On, Device statuses " & _powerStatus & "]")
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Sub Poweroff(ByVal WorkerID As Integer)
        Debug.Print("W" & WorkerID & ",  ResouceUser requesting Lock for Power OFF [" & _powerStatus & "]")
        SyncLock resourceLock
            _resource.TurnOff(WorkerID)
            _powerStatus = _resource.PowerState
            Debug.Print("W" & WorkerID & ", ResouceUser - Turned Off, Device statuses [" & _powerStatus & "]")
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    'Not going to work as it blocks the whole system when it could be
    'reseting other modems.
    Sub PowerCycle(ByVal WorkerID As Integer)
        SyncLock resourceLock
            Debug.Print("W" & WorkerID & ", ResourceUser - Requesting Power CYcle LockPower")
            _resource.PowerCycle(WorkerID)
            _powerStatus = _resource.PowerState
            Debug.Print("W" & WorkerID & ", ResourceUser - Power Cycled")
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Function CheckState() As String
        SyncLock resourceLock
            Return _resource.CheckState
            _powerStatus = _resource.PowerState
        End SyncLock
    End Function

End Class

============
```

RESOURCE - FOR ACTUAL WORK ON SHARED RESOURCE

```
'THis code would directly handle interactions
'with one specific com port that has already
'been configured and opened on the main thread.
Public Class jResource

    Private _ComPort As String
    Private _state As String
    Private _PowerState As String
    Private _CheckState As String

    'Record the com port used for this resource
    Public Property ComPort() As String
        Get
            Return _ComPort
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            Me._ComPort = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Returns the a particular status of the resouce
    Public ReadOnly Property CheckState As String
        Get
            'here I'd send a few command to the comm port
            'pick u the response and return it
            Return _state
        End Get
    End Property

    'The connected serial port is used to power cycle serveral devices
    'this property returns the state of all those devices.
    Public ReadOnly Property PowerState() As String
        Get
            Return _PowerState
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal name, ByRef state)
        Me._ComPort = name
        Me._state = state
        Me._PowerState = "11213141"
        Me._CheckState = "ON"
    End Sub

    'Simulate a off command sent by a worker
    'via its resourceUser object
    Public Sub TurnOn(ByVal intWorker As Integer)

         'simulate some work with the com port
        Dim myTimeOut As DateTime
        myTimeOut = Now.AddMilliseconds(500)
        Do Until Now > myTimeOut
        Loop
        'Set the status to show that Device is on.
        _PowerState = _PowerState.Replace(intWorker & "0", intWorker & "1")
        Debug.Print("W" & intWorker & ", Resource - issued TurnON, Device Statuses [" & _PowerState & "]")
    End Sub

    Public Sub TurnOff(ByVal intWorker As Integer)

        'simulate some work
        Dim myTimeOut As DateTime
        myTimeOut = Now.AddMilliseconds(500)
        Do Until Now > myTimeOut
        Loop
        'Here would send command to Com port    
        'Set the status to show that Device is Off.
        _PowerState = _PowerState.Replace(intWorker & "1", intWorker & "0")
        Debug.Print("W" & intWorker & ", Resource - issued TurnOFF, Device Statuses [" & _PowerState & "]")
    End Sub

    Public Sub PowerCycle(ByVal intWorker As Integer)

        Debug.Print("W" & intWorker & ", Resource - issued PowerCycle, Device Statuses [" & _PowerState & "]")

        'Here would send command to Com port    
        'Set the status to show that Device is Off.
        _PowerState = _PowerState.Replace(intWorker & "1", intWorker & "0")
        Debug.Print("W" & intWorker & ", Resource - issued TurnOFF, Device Statuses [" & _PowerState & "]")

        'simulate some work - takes a while for device to turn off
        Dim myTimeOut As DateTime
        myTimeOut = Now.AddMilliseconds(10000)
        Do Until Now > myTimeOut
        Loop

        'Here would send command to Com port    
        'Set the status to show that Device is Off.
        _PowerState = _PowerState.Replace(intWorker & "1", intWorker & "1")
        Debug.Print("W" & intWorker & ", Resource - issued TurnON, Device Statuses [" & _PowerState & "]")

        'simulate some work
        myTimeOut = Now.AddMilliseconds(10000)
        Do Until Now > myTimeOut
        Loop
        'Here would send command to Com port   
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Actually if Dan helped you, you should accept his answer and post the code that you want reviewed on [`CodeReview`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SO is not really the place to get a critical eye on your code. One thing I did notice is that in your `jResourceUser` Class's `CheckState` Method you are returning `resource.CheckState` before assigning `_powerStatus` therefore `_powerStatus = _resource.PowerState` is unreachable

Comment: Ok Thanks. I didnt know about CodeReview but sounds useful.